# Incorrect zooming when scrolling on the y or x-axis of flot charts

Tags: javascript, flot

I am using `flot.js` for a while now in order to create some line plots.

I was able to enable zooming via jquery.flot.navigate.js, zooming via the mousewheel.

The problem that I am facing now is that, when i am scrolling out and my mouse hovers over the xaxis letters the zooming goes crazy and zooms weirdly.

[image]

Here is what is happening:
[image]
It zooms IN on the yaxis even if i try to zoom OUT. I cannot explain it better coz its really weird . 
Please ask me if something is really unclear.

Any ideas why is this happening ?

Comment: Can you provide your code as a code snippet or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paschalidi/nu2rr58h/22/).
Try to zoom out when your mouse hovers at x axis letters or y axis letters on the left .

Comment: Ok, I see the strange behaviour now. It somehow depends on the values in `panRange` whether it shows or not, but I have no idea what is the underlying cause for it.

Comment: Yes I am at the same position . I juggled around with the values of the `panRange` but could find a rule that I could apply and solve my problem . The thing is that my plotting data are a bit dynamic, so I cannot set hard-coded values . Anyway if you thing of something please let me know .